# Hamming code detecting multiple errors

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

Say I have the matrix

$M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 0&0&1&1&1&1 \\
   0&1&1&0&0&1&1 \\
    1&0&1&0&1&0&1\\
  \end{array} } \right]$

Now I know that this string $0101011$ has one wrong bit. So I do the matrix multiplication and calculate the syndrome to get $1 1 1$ which corresponds to the 7th bit.

NOW what if I change the first bit of B=$0101011$ so it becomes  A=$1101011$ so now I have two error bits doing the matrix multiplication of $M*A$

I get a different syndrome that corresponds to a different bit,
I thought hamming codes could detect two errors, could someone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hamming code *can detect* the two errors; the syndrome is non-zero, whence the conclusion it is not correct, there were error(s).

However, the Hamming code *cannot correct* two errors (only one). Thus, if there are two errors and one tries to recover the original codeword this can fail. Yet, again one can reliably detect that there were error(s).

Comment: Im still confused in my example I compute the syndrome and get a totally different bit as having the error..  This doesn't tell me that two bits have different errors it just tells me that a different bit has the error.

Comment: You can only conclude some error(s) happened, as you did not 'receive' a valid codeword. You cannot conclude how many errors or which bits are wrong. If you *assume* (wrongly) that only one error happened, you would be mislead to decode to the wrong codeword. What you are trying to do implicitly makes this assumption "only one error happened."

Comment: hmmm.. but how can I assume B=0101011 isn't any more valid than A=1101011

Comment: You cannot, which is why you cannot correct the errors. You only can say that what you received is not right. But you cannot know what is right.

Comment: "reliably": as long as no serious errors occur such that the resulting code word is again a valid one.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören the last sentence was intended under the premise of the preceding one, that is, "there are two errors" (and not more).

Answer (score 1):

The Hamming code is a collection of code words such that every two of them is at least 3 apart in Hamming weight, and every word that is not a codeword is one bitflip away from a valid one. So if you flip one bit of a valid code word, you're still one away from the codeword you modified but still at least 2 away from another codeword. The principle of least distance decoding (most probable original codeword) tells us to correct the received word back to the original code word. 
But if we flip $2$ bits of a valid codeword $w_1$ we have distance $1$ to another valid codeword $w_2$ and of course $2$ to $w_1$. The decoding algorithm decodes to the wrong word $w_2$ (which is closer) but we did detect that we had to correct an error and we assumed we only had one (as this is more probable than $2$). So the Hamming code still detects a non-zero syndrome (hence an error).

In your example, the syndrome of the second vector is $110$ so we decode to $1101001$ (flip 6 as the syndrome is the 6th column) instead of the correct $0101010$ (which is a code word as the sum of row 2 and 3). The two codewords are indeed $3$ apart.

The syndrome can only be one of the 7 columns (all possible 7 values). two errors just looks like 1 error, and this canot be helped. We do detect an error.